# 20.10 Server WiFi drops connection frequently

Tags: server, wireless, 20.10, iwlwifi

We have setup an Ubuntu 20.10 Server having an Intel Wireless Card, the WiFi extremely shaky with frequent disconnections, almost once every minute. The details are as follows:
Ubuntu Version:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.10
Release:    20.10
Codename:   groovy
```

The Linux Kernel is:

```
5.8.0-43-generic
```

The hardware version is as follows:

```
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9462
```

The syslog has the following errors:

```
Apr 28 20:49:37 wpa_supplicant[916]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS
Apr 28 20:49:37 wpa_supplicant[916]: message repeated 2 times: [ wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS ]
Apr 28 20:49:37 wpa_supplicant[916]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=e4:c3:2a:21:6b:49 reason=4 locally_generated=1
Apr 28 20:49:38 ntpd[1153]: Deleting interface #82 wlp0s20f3, 192.168.1.22#123, interface stats: received=1, sent=1, dropped=0, active_time=83 secs
Apr 28 20:49:38 ntpd[1153]: Deleting interface #83 wlp0s20f3, fe80::46af:28ff:fe0a:9c9f%3#123, interface stats: received=0, sent=0, dropped=0, active_time=83 secs
Apr 28 20:49:38 wpa_supplicant[916]: wlp0s20f3: SME: Trying to authenticate with e4:c3:2a:21:6b:49 (SSID='test' freq=2412 MHz)
Apr 28 20:49:38 kernel: [ 4105.452210] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with e4:c3:2a:21:6b:49
Apr 28 20:49:38 kernel: [ 4105.457695] wlp0s20f3: send auth to e4:c3:2a:21:6b:49 (try 1/3)
Apr 28 20:49:38 wpa_supplicant[916]: wlp0s20f3: Trying to associate with e4:c3:2a:21:6b:49 (SSID='test' freq=2412 MHz)
Apr 28 20:49:38 kernel: [ 4105.561893] wlp0s20f3: send auth to e4:c3:2a:21:6b:49 (try 2/3)
Apr 28 20:49:38 kernel: [ 4105.564522] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
Apr 28 20:49:38 kernel: [ 4105.565689] wlp0s20f3: associate with e4:c3:2a:21:6b:49 (try 1/3)
Apr 28 20:49:38 kernel: [ 4105.570818] wlp0s20f3: RX AssocResp from e4:c3:2a:21:6b:49 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=5)
Apr 28 20:49:38 wpa_supplicant[916]: wlp0s20f3: Associated with e4:c3:2a:21:6b:49
Apr 28 20:49:38 wpa_supplicant[916]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Apr 28 20:49:38 kernel: [ 4105.574803] wlp0s20f3: associated
Apr 28 20:49:38 wpa_supplicant[916]: wlp0s20f3: WPA: Key negotiation completed with e4:c3:2a:21:6b:49 [PTK=CCMP GTK=TKIP]
Apr 28 20:49:38 wpa_supplicant[916]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to e4:c3:2a:21:6b:49 completed [id=0 id_str=]
```

The above syslog appears continously almost every minute.

The startup has the following error related to the driver:

```
[    6.028328] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-56.ucode failed with error -2
[    6.032948] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 55.d9698065.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-55.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    6.032975] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwl-debug-yoyo.bin failed with error -2
```

If anyone has faced a similar issues and have been able to resolve, please do let me know.
We have disabled the default netplan and are using ifupdown+wpa_supplicant
Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

"beacon loss" reports crop up here after more intel wifi card owners upgraded to a >=5.1 kernel. The important log lines are:

```
wpa_supplicant: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS
wpa_supplicant: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=.. reason=4 locally_generated=1
```

The gist: iwlwifi since kernel 5.1 is [more strict](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=babea2d4fe76c6515da6231e8d940044bad686b1) in disconnecting when a constant number of beacons were unseen. While there can different reasons for the loss itself (access points settings / spectrum environment / bugs), the current value is too disruptive from a user perspective if a stable connection has priority over optimal performance or power saving features.

You can read up on it in bugid [#203709](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=203709). A workaround [patch](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=203709#c172) was proposed in January to make the constant a runtime parameter outside kernel builds. If you want to give this a go (it's modifying 4 files and ~2h for the compile on a Laptop), follow the [BuildYourOwnKernel](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel) docs and then set module params at boot or write to `/sys/module/iwlwifi/parameters/beacon_timeout` and keep a watch on this until a solution is merged.

Answer (score 0):

In this discussion thread [patch](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=203709#c172) one of the member mentioned to switch the WIFI mode from

> 80211n support

to type 11bg support, help solved my problem.
Ping latency is very low and yjrtr is almost no more CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS report.

`ping` low latency:

[image: Ping low latency]

no more CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS report:

[[image: no more CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS report]

I am using TP-Link Wireless N Router WR840N
Model No. TL-WR840N and it have 2 WIFI modes:

```
a. 11bg mixed
b. 11bgn mixed
```

My Debian-10 OS,
$ uname -a
Linux debian-pc 4.19.0-21-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.249-2 (2022-06-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Do you know for sure this works on a Ubuntu system? This is a Ubuntu only support site.

Comment: Firstly, i did not pay attention that this is ubuntu only support. Was landed from google-search, and feel free to take down or remove my answer/post if you think not well-address the issue. IMHO, ubuntu is one of Debian derivation distro, though.